# LINQ to XElement

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to select all **xyzitem** from below XElement. I want to the know best way to select all **xyzitem** using LINQ or Lambda. I want to print value of "No" tag of each xyzitem. Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

```
<Soap:Body xmlns:Soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<UpdateMultiple_Result xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/xyzitem">
    <xyzitem_List>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>N2610</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>BB8100</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>SW810I</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>8525PDA</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>MM-A900M</No>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>MA464LL/A</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>LX.FR206.001</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>VGN-TXN27N/B</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>M285-E</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
        <xyzitem>               
            <No>CN_3</No>
            <Description>productDescription</Description>               
        </xyzitem>
    </xyzitem_List>
</UpdateMultiple_Result>
</Soap:Body>
```

Thanks

Kishore K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have namespace declared, so you should use it to provide names of elements:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/xyzitem";
var numbers = from i in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "xyzitem")
              select (string)i.Element(ns + "No");
```